# Cython generated module can't be used because of undefined symbol

Tags: python, cpython, python-extensions

The python extension lsblib.so is created by cython and distutils, the build command generated from distutil is as following:

```
/gpfs/software/openlava_sqa/3.3.3/etc/../include/lsbatch.h:1681: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
gcc -pthread -shared -L/gpfs/DEV/PLT/software/anaconda2-4.0.0/lib -Wl,-rpath=/gpfs/DEV/PLT/software/anaconda2-4.0.0/lib,--no-as-needed build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/openlava/lsblib.o /gpfs/software/openlava_sqa/3.3.3/etc/../lib/liblsfint.a /gpfs/software/openlava_sqa/3.3.3/etc/../lib/liblsf.a /gpfs/software/openlava_sqa/3.3.3/etc/../lib/liblsbatch.a -L/gpfs/software/openlava_sqa/3.3.3/etc/../lib -L/gpfs/DEV/PLT/software/anaconda2-4.0.0/lib -llsfint -llsf -llsbatch -lnsl -ltools -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/openlava/lsblib.so -g
```

Note that, linked the four libraries twice by lsblib.o+lib*.a and -lXX, the target module is **lsblib.so**

```
-llsfint -llsf -llsbatch -lnsl -ltools
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/openlava/lsblib.o /gpfs/software/openlava_sqa/3.3.3/etc/../lib/liblsfint.a /gpfs/software/openlava_sqa/3.3.3/etc/../lib/liblsf.a /gpfs/software/openlava_sqa/3.3.3/etc/../lib/liblsbatch.a
```

When I import the module:

> /gpfs/software/openlava_sqa/3.3.3/lib/**liblsbatch.so.0**: undefined
>   symbol: mergeResreq

However, the compiled **lsblib.so** has the symbol

> 000000000009dc9b T mergeResreq

and the symbol mergeResreq is in the liblsfint.a and liblsfinit.so.0.0.1

```
nm /gpfs/software/openlava_sqa/3.3.3/lib/liblsfint.so.0.0.1 |grep merge
0000000000010017 T mergeResreq
00000000000161d5 t mergeW
nm /gpfs/software/openlava_sqa/3.3.3/lib/liblsfint.a |grep merge
00000000000041ff T mergeResreq
0000000000000581 t mergeW
```

Why when importing the module, it finds the symbol in the wrong lsbatch.so?It do not use the one in lsblib.so and even if I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it doesn't use the one lsfint.so.0.0.1